# Rapidminer and decision tree weights

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, feature-selection, decision-trees, rapidminer

In Rapidminer, are the decision tree's weights a measure of the "importance" of attributes in the splitting procedure ?

If yes, why is useful to know these weights ?
Are there better methods to know the most discriminant features in a data set ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically yes, weights are used for attribute or feature importance. Gradient Boosted Tree weights are the best for feature importance in my tests for most of data. But there are other methods like PCA, Weights by Correlation but the performance would be worse. Also deep learning first two layers (input and first hidden layer) can be used to measure importance of features.